# Material design pattern for search in drop-down list?

Tags: search, material-design, drop-down-list

I'm looking for a material design pattern to achieve [live search](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search) in a drop-down list using bootstrap-select.

[image]

Also, I played with chips, but I don't like them and want to use something different.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Auto complete text field guidelines](https://material.google.com/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-auto-complete-text-field) which look like this:

[image]

I've also seen them implemented in more of a combobox style like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you have a Search function along with a checkbox combobox in the same component? Meaning, a user can search a long list of a checkbox list?